# netlogo CSV import encoding

Tags: netlogo

I am using script below to import from .csv file. Problem is that I want to replace values that in the file are strings or empty (for example #NULL! and empty cell). If I use condition like:

```
if value = "#NULL!" or value = "" [print "Replace value"]
```

Nothing happens. I would imagine it is the problem of the encoding or is there some other "feature" involved with netlogo. I also tried to save csv with notepad to get rid of Excel "additons".

CSV import code

```
to openFile
  file-open "/import/import.csv"
  set fileList []
  while [not file-at-end?] [
    set csv file-read-line
    set csv word csv ","  ; add comma for loop termination
    let mylist []  ; list of values
    while [not empty? csv] [
      let $x position "," csv
      let $item substring csv 0 $x  ; extract item
      carefully [set $item read-from-string $item][] ; convert if number
      set mylist lput $item mylist  ; append to list
      set csv substring csv ($x + 1) length csv  ; remove item and comma
    ]
    set fileList lput mylist fileList
  ]
  ;show fileList
  file-close
end
```

Comment: That's not really an answer to your question, but: you should probably be using the `csv` extension (https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/csv.html). It is bundled with NetLogo and it would make your life much easier.

Comment: This is a good point. But in regards to my existing code the main problem is that I am compering list item and string. How can I say that list item is string. In python I just change it with: `srt(value)`   I have similar problem that I want to add value to sting that I use as dynamic dir. So perhaps there is a way to encode variable into string.

Comment: `word` will convert any value to a string.